# mongoose query search All

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I set the query and it works. However, when a user has selected zero category, I want to return everything.

```
query: {
    category: { $in: categories }
        }
```

This is the query in mongoose. How can I set this to `return all the docs` when `categories` is empty array?

Comment: you can put condition in your client side, like `let query = {}; if(categories.length) { query: { category: { $in: categories } } }`

Comment: I thought there might be a variable that does it in-house. But, I will just do that! thanks mate